# Using DynamicResource in another resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have SolidColorBrush and DrawingImage (vector icon) as XAML resources, both on a global level, in Application.Resources. DrawingImage have GeometryDrawing inside which uses aforesaid brush as DynamicResource.

Looks like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushPrimaryColor"/>

<DrawingImage x:Key="iconMain">
   <DrawingImage.Drawing>
       <DrawingGroup>
           <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource brushPrimaryColor}"/>
       </DrawingGroup>
   </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

It is working initially, but changing (swapping for new brush) *brushPrimaryColor* at a runtime does not reflect on *iconMain*. DrawingImage is also used as DynamicResource, not frozen and i can change it directly in code.

Basically what i want is to make changeable palette from few brushes for set of vector icons. Is it possible to do with resources, or should i copy resource at a runtime and bind to that copy instead?

Comment: Brushes in resources are frozen and readonly, or at least it is their default behaviour. Would like to now if that can be changed somehow

Comment: It would work when you move the resources to MainWindow.Resources.

Comment: Thanks, now i see that brushes in MainWindow.Resources are not frozen, so it would work. Hovewer, it would be rather uncovinient and messy to dump all brushes and images in there. I was planning to use resource dictionary, and there is no merged dictionaries in MainWindow.Resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most resources that extend `Freezable` and are defined in the *App.xaml* `ReeourceDictionary` are frozen by default (by the XAML engine). For example, brushes defined in the global `ResourceDictionary` (*App.xaml*) are expected to be shared across the application. In other words, the name scope of *App.xaml* is global and resources with the same resource key cannot appear at a different node in the resource tree (they are unique). It's safe to assume that *App.xaml* resources are shared. Therefore, to improve performance the XAML engine will freeze every `Brush` defined in *App.xaml*, based on the assumption that `Brush` resources will be treated like static resources.

To change this behavior, you must explicitly instruct the XAML engine to not share this kind of resources. You do this by setting the `x:Shared` attribute to `false`. This way the XAML engine will not assume that resources are referenced as static resource and thus will not freeze the `Freezable` resource.
As mentioned before the default behavior is that the XAML parser will share resources. The `x:Shared` attribute therefore defaults to `true`.

To solve your issue, set `x:Shared` on the resource to `false`:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<!-- Prevent global Brush from being frozen by the XAMK engine
     by setting x:Shared to False -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushPrimaryColor"
                 x:Shared="False" />

<DrawingImage x:Key="iconMain">
   <DrawingImage.Drawing>
       <DrawingGroup>
           <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource brushPrimaryColor}"/>
       </DrawingGroup>
   </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```